# Stanford NLP core Sentiment Analysis using Naive Bayes and SVM classifierJava

Tags: svm, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

Hi I am new to Sentiment Analysis and I am currently using StanfordNLP core api. I am able to get sentiments from sentences, positive, neutral and negative.
Is there any examples I could follow in using the different classifier algorithms provided by the api, such as Naive Bayes and SVM to get the different sentiment score for comparisons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no other algorithms supported for sentiment analysis. You can, however, train your own without too much difficulty: bigram features with a simple classifier work quite well for sentiment tasks.

Comment: I do know that for StanfordNLP does provides the classifer API. But somehow, I am unable to find any examples on how to go about using it. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml but the core API does includes the classifer.

Comment: At a high level, you should featurize a sentence into a `Counter` (probably `ClassicCounter`), create a `Datum` with the `Counter` and the output label, add the `Datum`s to a `Dataset`, create a `ClassifierFactory`, and then train a classifier from that.